# simple update two fields in php gives error

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to update some fields in a mysql database from php. This always gives me error, and I don't know why. Could you have a quick look?

```
         $sqlupdate_ = "UPDATE $db SET city=$city, country=$country WHERE  userIP=$ip;";
              $sqlupdate = mysql_query($sqlupdate_);
              echo $sqlupdate_;

 if($sqlupdate){

      //The query returned true - now do whatever you like here.
      echo 'success';

 }else{

      //The query returned false - you might want to put some sort of error reporting here. Even logging the error to a text file is fine.
      echo "error: ";

 }
```

Comment: and what exactly is the error message?

Comment: You need to quote strings.

Comment: Thank you, adding quotes fixed it :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all:, use mysqli or PDO since mysql functions are depracated.

Second: avoid sql injections with escape your strings.

I think, your problem is that, your city, country and ip are varchars not integers, so you need to add quotes around them, and you want to update your table not your database.

Try to echoes your query and run directly in mysql.

```
$sqlupdate_ = "UPDATE " . mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $db). " SET city= '" .mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $city) ."', country='".mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $country)."' WHERE  userIP='".mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $ip)."'";
```

Comment: Note that escaping a table- or column name has no effect at all as far as sql injection prevention goes. The OP would need a whitelist is the value is user-provided.

Comment: i escaped the variables, not the column names.

Comment: You're escaping the table name.

Comment: i am escaping the table name too. and why is that a problem? we do not know nothing about his code. what if $db is a global variable, and it can be overwritten? `UPDATE '; DELETE FROM ...;` could be also an sql injection.

Comment: I guess I need to learn this then. Thank you for not only fixing my issues (quotes) but also telling me about PDO and sql injections. Really good answer. Cheers.

Comment: @lolka_bolka Exactly, and `mysqli_real_escape_string()` does not prevent that so using it adds a false sense of security. Only a whitelist prevents sql injection for table- and column names.

Comment: what you are talking about? `mysqli_real_escape_string` is for this. 1st, i do not escaped any column names, only variables. 2nd. If i overwrited the `$db` with value `'; DELETE FROM ....` the function will escape the `'` sign with `\'` so it will throw an error, and won't executed.

Comment: @lolka_bolka Table- and column names don't use straight quotes so you could inject without using these and `mysqli_real_escape_string()` would do nothing about it.

Comment: please explain me, why are you always talking about column names? And i think, you are not right. You can terminate an sql query everywhere, and inject your on code. so escaping any variables in a query is required.

Comment: Forget the column names then, just the table name. If multiple queries is enabled, you could just use `some_table set id=id; DELETE FROM some_table; -- `. There is no character that `mysqli_real_escape_string()` would escape in that value and everything after `--` would be reduced to a mysql comment. So using `mysqli_real_escape_string()` you have an sql injection problem...

Answer (score -1):

to see the error, you could use try/catch like so:

```
<?php

function throw_ex($er){
    throw new Exception($er);
}

try {
    $sqlupdate_ = "UPDATE $db SET city=$city, country=$country WHERE  userIP=$ip;";
    $sqlupdate = mysql_query($sqlupdate_);
    echo $sqlupdate_;

    if($sqlupdate){
        echo 'success';
    } else {
    throw_ex(mysql_error());
}

} catch (Exception $e) {
    echo $e;
}
```

hope this helps